# Checking input box whether it is focused or not

Tags: php, javascript

I want to change the appearance of the web page according to an input is focused or not, If it is not focused, it will display something and if it is focused, replace something with another things simultaneously.How can i do that that?Can it be done with PHP?
Thanks

Comment: I think you are used to develop in .NET where you can just drag the boxes into the page and let them refresh them. But they add a piece of javascript too, that let the page refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will definitely have to use JavaScript for this if your making changes beyond changing styling of the `checkbox`. If its imperative to get information from the server on focus you could make an ajax request to a php file to have data returned. The link below is an example using JavaScript and `onfocus` to change a div elsewhere on the page.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vSGWd/1/)**

Simple snippet.

```
var check = document.getElementById("YourIdOrWhatHaveYou"),

check.onfocus= function(){
    // DO your thang!
}
```

Comment: This was what i wanted but this is working IE not google chrome.Is it the problem of my browser or is it not realy working with chrome?How can i make it work for all browsers?

Comment: Try out the demo link I posted in Chrome, it works for me, I just tested the demo link in IE which worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

no, you'll need css, see the

[`:focus` selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)

(php is serverside code only, which means it cannot see if the user has put focus on anything, javascript could do it but css would be best in this case.)

Comment: Using only css can make it simultaneously?I think doing this with css may require refreshing. Am i right?Sorry, i am new:(

Comment: Focus selector would enable him to change the style of that said element, but not change other things on the page.

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot do this for you as it is a server side language and doesnt know about focus.

If you want to change the the appearance of something based on focus, @red-X already mentioned the `:focus` selector in css.

If you want modify the content of the object or others in the DOM based on if something has focus, you'll need to use javascript, the [jquery](http://jquery.com/) library allows you to use the same `:focus` selector to detect if an object has focus or when it gets/losses focus.